# Divergent real sequence for which $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists a \in \mathbb{R}: |x_n-a|<\epsilon$ for almost all n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Looking at the definition of convergence:

$\exists a \in \mathbb{R}\forall \epsilon >0: |x_n-a|<\epsilon$ for almost all n

I switched the order of the first two quantifiers. Is there a sequence for which

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists b \in \mathbb{R}: |x_n-b|<\epsilon$  for almost all n

holds but it's not convergent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sequence satisfying this condition is Cauchy, and therefore convergent to some finite limit by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$.  To see this, suppose $\epsilon > 0$.  Then there exists $b$ such that $|x_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for almost all $n$.  In order words, for such a $b$, there exists $N$ such that $|x_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $n \ge N$.  But then whenever $m, n \ge N$, we have
$$|x_m - x_n| = |(x_m - b) - (x_n - b)| \le |x_m - b| + |x_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.$$